# How do you observe black holes up close?

Tags: black-holes

So in the context of sci-fi movies and video games where characters get up close and personal to the black hole without getting too close and falling into the gravity well. Is this even possible? Black holes move through space, so if you are in front of one, will it move away from/toward you? Will you orbit the black hole? Will you be sort of dragged along by its gravity but not fall into the event horizon?

What happens?

Comment: Hi buiud, and welcome to Worldbuilding; unfortunately, this isn't really worldbuilding - the behaviour of objects near black holes has been extensively modelled.  [The Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/what-is-the-closest-one-could-get-to-a-black-hole-and-still-stand-a-realistic) has what's probably the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Some of the answers in this [related question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138503/how-close-could-a-planet-get-to-a-super-massive-black-hole-before-being-destroye) might give you a fair impression of what it would be like close-up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even possible?

To get up close without falling in? Yep, but it depends how you define "close", how big your black hole is and how effective your spaceship engines are.

Event horizons are quite compact things, relatively speaking... the Schwarzschild radius of an object is defined as $$r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

where $G$ is the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant), $M$ is the mass of the object and $c$ is the speed of light. If our sun were to be magically and instantly turned into a black hole, the Schwarzschild radius would only be 3km. You need to be far enough away from the black hole that your rocket engines can still boost you to escape velocity. Escape velocity is defined as $v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$. If you've got something fancy like a [beam core antimatter rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter_rocket) you could get closer than 9 times the Schwarzschild radius. If you've got a slower-than-light warp drive you might be able to go right up to it. If you reach or cross the event horizon, you're only getting out with magical time-travelling faster-than-light travel (which is a whole new kettle of fish), assuming you survived the journey in, which you might not... small black holes can [spaghettify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) you (yes, that is the technical term) due to the intense [tidal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) as you get close to them.

Of course, most (probably all) natural black holes will be somewhat bigger than our sun. [Saggitarius A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*), the supermassive black hole at the centre of our galaxy, has an event horizon at 12.5 million km from the centre, but that still means that an object as far away from it as Mercury is from the Sun is well clear of it.

What you *do* have to worry about however is the [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk) formed from matter falling into and orbiting around the black hole. This can be very large and very hot and as a result a strong source of x-rays and other hazardous radiation. The black hole accretion disks in [active galactic nuclei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_galactic_nucleus) such as [quasars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar) are amongst the brightest objects in the universe. You can also get [relativistic jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet#Relativistic_jet) of very hot, very fast particles shooting out along the axis of rotation of the accretion disk, and getting in the way of one of those will probably toast you in short order (see also: [blazars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazar)).

> Black holes move through space, so if you are in front of one, will it move away from/toward you?

Everything moves in space. Our sun is orbiting our galaxy at about 200km/s, which is pretty fast, but we don't really notice that because we're orbiting it. Anyone investigating a black hole will probably be orbiting that, too. It will only come as close as the [periapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) of your orbit, which will be predictable. (Incidentally, I like Landis' term for the closest approach to a black hole... [*perimelasma*](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/perimelasma.htm). There are other more boring words in the scientific literature, though).

So long as you're orbiting far enough away from the black hole that your engines can reach escape velocity, you'll be just fine, apart from the aforementioned vast radiation hazards that will likely accompany any black hole of interest. Black holes *without* an accretion disk could exist, of course, but they'd be a lot harder to find and so be a lot less likely to be investigated.

Comment: Schwarzschild. The most commonly misspelled scientist.

Comment: @ths noted ;-) I'll patch that up in a bit.

Comment: "Schild" is German for shield (or one of those hanging commercial signs which look a bit like a shield); it is even pronounced "shield". I never got it why people can always spell Roth-Schild ("Red Shield") correctly but have trouble with Schwarz-Schild ("Black Shield"). It is because one wouldn't dare misspell the name of a rich and powerful family?

Comment: @AlexP its nice that you think I'd be able to spell that name correctly, but I'm not sure your optimism is warranted. (also, in english at least, it tends to be pronounced "roths-child", lending itself to the correct spelling, but "schwarz-child" does not)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in space you are never still. You are always in relative motion with respect to something else.

Same holds for a black hole: you will have a relative velocity with respect to it. And as long as your trajectory doesn't cross the event horizon, you will be orbiting the black hole like it was a body of its mass. The type of this orbit depends on the relative velocity you have, and in first approximation can be a closed orbit ( the ellipses we know from our solar system) or an open one (an hyperbolic arc).

However if the black hole as an accretion disk it will glow with high energy radiation generated by the dissipating momentum of the trapped matter. So being too close will kill you way before the gravity of the black hole can crush you. And more over if you start bumping into that matter you will lose momentum too, being captured by the black hole or crushed to death into an impact.

That said we have been able to observe a black hole in a distant galaxy staying here on Earth, so you don't need to get with your nose poking on the black hole to observe it.

Comment: Orbits can not go down to the event horizon. At the EH, the only way 'out' is to go directly away from the EH, at the speed of light. The closest point where you can travel parallel to the EH and not fall in is 1.5 times the schwarzschild radius. Of course orbiting at that distance requires going at the speed of light, so the practical limit of how close you could approach a black hole (and return), is much higher.